# How Specifically do Sampling methods help in training Machine learning models?

Tags: probability, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I get the gist of sampling methods in probability. These algorithms were developed while building the Atom Bomb to estimate some distribution. The idea was just to try a simulation and note the results. And keep doing it for long enough, you will get a distribution over the outcomes, that is your probability.

Now, I am really having trouble understanding how do these methods work in machine learning.

Consider a topic model.

This is a probabilistic model like $P(x, z, y)$, where z is the hidden variable and there are distributions linking $x$ y and $z$.

The model is generative so the output is only on $x$ and $y$.

How does sampling method help here? How are the simulations run?

Could you explain how MCMC and Metropolis-Hastings are related to these? How do they actually work, what do they compute? How can you compute them without any optimization?

I really want to understand these methods and try some probabilistic programming but I am not getting the hang of it.

Comment: I don't yet get what the actual question is, it seems that there are several at once. To get started, you could look as an entry point at the MCMC description in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo. Maybe you could refine the question, so that it is better suited to the question-answer format.

Answer (score 1):

In general sampling methods can be used wherever you need to estimate some expected value.

> How does sampling method help here? How are the simulations run?

Say $x$ is input, $y$ is target and $z$ the hidden variable, and we want to know $p(y|x)$ then
$$p(y|x)=\int p(y,z|x) dz\approx\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mp(y|z_i,x)$$
where $z_i$ are samples from $p(z|x)$.

> Could you explain how MCMC and Metropolis-Hastings are related to these? How do they actually work, what do they compute?

In general generating samples from a high dimensional distribution is not easy, so MCMC is used to draw samples $z_i$ from $p(z|x)$.

What MCMC (and many other sampling methods) computes is roughly to simulate samples from $p(z|x)$ by making use of another distribution that we can easily get samples from (say a uniform distribution between 0 and 1).

> How can you compute them without any optimization?

If we treat $z$ as a parameter, of course we can use optimization to solve $z$
$$z_{MAP}=\arg\max_zp(z|x)=\arg\max_zp(x|z)p(z) $$
then $p(y|x)\approx p(y|z_{MAP},x)$.

So the difference between optimization and sampling is, by optimization (MAP) we estimate $p(y|x)$ using the most likely sample, by sampling we estimate $p(y|x)$ using a collection of samples.